# Can you use 2 java nio file systems in one program?

Tags: java, scala, filesystems, java.nio.file

I am writing a project that will generate a folder structure from a template folder structure (which I package inside my jar as a resource). I want to keep all the resources inside my program's jar file, so my users will only have to know about this one jar file, without having to worry about a separate resource folder.

I have this code here (Scala code using java libraries):

```
package ru.company.project

import java.nio.file.{FileSystems, Files, Path, Paths}
import java.util

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val uri = this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("resource1").toURI

    // create file system
    val env = new util.HashMap[String, String]()
    env.put("create", "true")
    val jarFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)

    val file = Paths.get(uri)

    Files.walk(file).forEach(f => {
      println(f)
      if (Files.isRegularFile(f))
        copyToLocal(f)
    })

    jarFS.close()
  }

  def copyToLocal(file: Path): Unit = {
    val content = Files.readAllLines(file)
    Files.write(file, content)
  }
}
```

It is able to read the resources from my jar file just fine, but when it executes `Files.write(file, content)` in `copyToLocal`, it fails with this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: resource1/another_text_file.txt
        at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.newOutputStream(ZipFileSystem.java:516)
        at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.newOutputStream(ZipPath.java:790)
        at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:285)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.write(Unknown Source)
        at ru.company.project.Main$.copyToLocal(Main.scala:28)
        at ru.company.project.Main$.$anonfun$main$1(Main.scala:20)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
        at ru.company.project.Main$.main(Main.scala:17)
        at ru.company.project.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

This is because I somehow need to use another file system to write outside the jar file, but it seems that when you do `FilesSystems.newFileSystem` it creates a global one.

So, how do I create another file system and use 2 file systems at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method `copyToLocal(...)` is wrong. It reads from a file and then writes back all read lines to the same file again. There is no 'magic mechanism' that 'knows' which file system to use for reading and which for writing.

**So the main question is:** *How does an operation like `Files.write(path, content)` know, which `FileSystem` to use?*

**Answer:** *It uses the `FileSystem` that was used to create the path.*

**Longer answer:** A `Path` object is always associated to a `FileSystem`. It always denotes a file or folder of a *specific file system*, so it holds both, the file system and the path itself.

All static methods of `Files`, like `Files.delete(path)` or `Files.list(path)` use the file systems associated with the given path. Methods that operate on more than one path, like `Files.copy(source, target, options)` are optimized in case both paths are from the same file system (which is the common case), but should also work across different file systems (as in your case).

If you use (1) the factory method `Paths.get(first, ...more)`, the path is always associated to the **default** `FileSystem`. If your use (2) `Paths.get(uri)`, all installed file system providers are searched for the file system. If (3) the `getPath(...)` method of a concrete `FileSystem` is used, the path is associated with this file system.

So you should use any of these three ways to control the file system that should be associated to your path, e.g.:

```
try(FileSystem jarFs = ...;
    FileSystem defaultFs = ...) {

    Path source = jarFs.getPath(...);
    Path target = defaultFs.getPath(...);

    Files.copy(source, target);
}
```

*(code snippet is in Java, as I don't know Scala)*

This means for your code:

```
...
val jarPath = Paths.get(uri)

Files.walk(jarPath).forEach(jarFile => {
  println(jarFile)
  if (Files.isRegularFile(jarFile))
    Files.copy(jarFile, createLocalPathFor(jarFile))
})
...

def createLocalPathFor(path: Path): Path = {
  // TODO: create a local path for the given file
  // TODO: which local folder? which local file name?
  return Paths.get(...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks and what do I write instead of "..."? I need to access the files inside jar and inside local fs.

Comment: The "..." depends on the local folder and file name of the local target file. You will have to "compute" it based on the file name in the jar file. See my extended answer for some approach.

Comment: Hm, it seems there is at least something else wrong with your code: You are using the wrong URI to create the jar file system. The URI should have the pattern `jar:<uri-of-jar>`. In your case, it seems to be only `<uri-of-jar>`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

Comment: Well, it still works, apparently it plugs in the "jar:" part automatically when you do this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("resource1"). "resource1" is a folder inside the jar that is executing the code.

Comment: https://github.com/paulpaul1076/UsingJarFileResources/tree/develop here's the code that I run, you can run "mvn clean package" this will build a fat jar and also put the "resource" folder into this jar. Then you can run the jar file and you will see that it works.

Comment: Ah, ok - I first though, `resource1` is the name of the jar file you want to extract (and the jar file is packed inside the jar file that contains the code). But now I see, you want to read files from the jar file that contains the code itself, and `resource1` is just the folder you want to extract. Then it should work, I think.

Comment: Yes, it works, I ran it multiple times and it works as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220552/discussion-between-isnot2bad-and-hey-you).